# automating of Siebel app via COM/Siebel Application Server: how to get FIELD names?

Tags: c#, .net, com, ui-automation, siebel

For a .Net WCF service I'm using COM/Siebel Application Server to automate Siebel 6.3.0.316 but I haven't figured out how to find out field names. I can query Siebel views for their names, but I'm not finding any way to grab Siebel field names, in bulk or individually. And all the methods operating on fields require filed name(s) as a parameter.

Anybody has any experience with this or any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: To be more specific, I'd like to make calls like this:

SiebelApplicationServer.SiebelBusComp myBC = Instance.ActiveBusComp(ref errCode) as SiebelApplicationServer.SiebelBusComp;
 
myBC.ActivateField("Tax ID Number", ref errCode);

But it order to make this call: I need to know the field name value(in this case "Tax ID Number"), and that's the problem, I don't know how to determine it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

every meta data you would like to get is stored in Siebel in something called Repository. You can access it like any other regular Business Component (actually their names starts with "Repository "). The data you would like to get are accessible by BC named:  **Repository Field**. The fields that might be of your interest are:

- **Name** - keeping the name of the field on particular BC
- **Inactive** - flag indicating if the field is active or not
- **Parent Name** - name of BC owning this field
- **Repository Id** - id if repository (you just need to make sure to take out the current one)

Other repository BCs that might interest you:

- **Repository Business Component** - containing list of all Business Components
- **Repository Repository** - containg list of all Siebel Repositories (for example you can find the active one here)